# Query Optimization, (subquery) (sql-transact)

Tags: sql, query-optimization, having, subquery

This is the code I have to optimize, I managed to get it to half of the starting cost only with indexes and changing the LIKE for a SUBSTRING sentence. My problem is now with the sub-query in the last line, and the SUM lines in the select, I believe I have to get rid of those by creating a new table or column but can't get it done.

```
SELECT 
C.LastName as Customer , e.LastName as SalesPerson, s.ProductID,
p.Name as ProductName, SUM( s.Quantity ) as quantity, 
SUM ( p.Price * s.Quantity ) as amount 
FROM dbo.Sales s, dbo.Customers c, dbo.Employees e, dbo.Products p 
WHERE 
 s.CustomerID = c.CustomerID and 
 s.ProductID = p.ProductID and 
 s.SalesPersonID = e.EmployeeID and
 p.Name like 'Paint%' 
GROUP BY C.LastName , e.LastName , s.ProductID, p.Name 
HAVING sum ( s.Quantity ) < 
(select AVG(s2.Quantity) from dbo.Sales s2 where s2.ProductID=s.ProductID )
```

Any help is welcome, thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you used EXPLAIN to see the optimization plan?  Unfortunately, the HAVING sum() is probably going to force you to read a lot of rows.  Is data redesign an option?  Is it possible to make sure this query runs only rarely (say with a cron job) and is cached somewhere like a text file or a sales_volume table?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: @TomHaws u mean EXECUTION? Yes I did and just like you said the HAVING  and the subquery is giving me 70% of the whole estimated cost. Redesign is allowed.

It's SQL Server.

Comment: The more I look at this, the more is looks like a bona fide complicated query that probably doesn't need up-to-the-second currency.  I think my preferred solution, if the demand is very frequent, would be to serve a periodically cached result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't test it right now, but I think this should work:

```
SELECT c.LastName as Customer , 
       e.LastName as SalesPerson, 
       s.ProductID,
       p.Name as ProductName, 
       SUM(s.Quantity) as quantity, 
       SUM(p.Price * s.Quantity) as amount 
  FROM dbo.Sales s, 
  JOIN dbo.Customers c
    ON c.CustomerID = s.CustomerID 
  JOIN dbo.Employees e
    ON e.EmployeeID = s.SalesPersonID
  JOIN dbo.Products p 
    ON p.ProductID = s.ProductID
   AND p.Name like 'Paint%'
  JOIN (SELECT ProductID,
               AVG(Quantity) as avg_Quantity
          FROM dbo.Sales) s2 
    ON s2.ProductID = s.ProductID
 GROUP BY c.LastName , e.LastName , s.ProductID, p.Name 
HAVING sum(s.Quantity) <  AVG(s2.avg_Quantity)
```

Comment: In fact, I think you could replace AVG(s2.avg_Quantity) with Min(s2.avg_Quantity); the effect should be the same but I guess that Min() will be (a fraction) faster than AVG(). (not tested, simply thinking out loud, but I'd guess implementing AVG() requires a bit more logic)

Answer (score 0):

If using SQL Server you can streamline this a little with window functions:

```
WITH cte AS (   SELECT  C.LastName AS Customer
                      , e.LastName AS SalesPerson
                      , s.ProductID
                      , p.Name AS ProductName
                      , SUM(s.Quantity) AS quantity
                      , SUM(p.Price * s.Quantity) AS amount
                      , SUM(SUM(s.Quantity)) OVER (PARTITION BY s.ProductID)*1.0/SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY s.ProductID) AS Avg_Qty
                FROM     dbo.Sales s
                    JOIN dbo.Customers c ON s.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
                    JOIN dbo.Employees e ON s.SalesPersonID = e.EmployeeID
                    JOIN dbo.Products p ON s.ProductID = p.ProductID
                WHERE   s.Name LIKE 'Paint%'
                GROUP BY C.LastName
                      , e.LastName
                      , s.ProductID
                      , p.Name
            )
SELECT * 
FROM  cte
WHERE quantity < Avg_Qty
```

Adding a `Name_Category` field or similar to avoid using `LIKE` would help.

Answer (score 0):

This is equal to your statement but much faster:

```
SELECT 
C.LastName as Customer , e.LastName as SalesPerson, s.ProductID,
p.Name as ProductName, SUM( s.Quantity ) as quantity, 
SUM ( p.Price * s.Quantity ) as amount 
FROM dbo.Sales s
INNER JOIN dbo.Products p ON s.ProductID = p.ProductID /*AND p.Name like 'Paint%' --optionally place filter here if you like*/
INNER JOIN (SELECT s2.ProductID SalesProductID, AVG(s2.Quantity)AVG_Quantity FROM dbo.Sales s2 GROUP BY s2.ProductID)ProductSales ON ProductSales.SalesProductID = s.ProductID
INNER JOIN dbo.Customers c ON s.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
INNER JOIN dbo.Employees e ON s.SalesPersonID = e.EmployeeID
WHERE p.Name like 'Paint%' 
GROUP BY C.LastName , e.LastName , s.ProductID, p.Name
```